# Date accessed and visited

Tags: usb

So I went to upload photos onto a external hard drive that belongs to my SO ( I have they're  permission to use it) but when i went in I saw saved photos of engagement rings. Probably to show my parents as they dont have smart phones or laptops, they're old fashioned and not good with technology. Can they tell I went into the harddrive? I dont want to ruin the surprise cuz I know they would be heartbroken and can never keep a secret so this is a big deal.  When I check the date last accessed/visited it shows the last time they were in there and not me.

Comment: If you opened the photo (different that just displaying the thumbnail for the photo) then the file access time would have been updated.  However, much of the meta data is not even display normally, unless the user specifically has indicated they want it displayed.  Furthermore, I know I don't typically write down when I last accessed a file, so you are probably safe.  The answer to your question is entirely based on what actions you performed, something you sadly, didn't explicitly indicate.  Just opening a folder full of photos isn't enough detail (unless that is actually all you did).

Answer (score 0):

Date accessed is just that - you accessed, the date will update to "now".
If you just looked at a folder of small thumbnail images, it wouldn't update, but if you actually opened each image to look properly, it would.

Your get out of jail free card in this instance is that even a young, savvy user would only notice if they looked for the info specifically. This is information that isn't seen in any general view of a folder, you have to know what to look for… & go look at it.

No-one else will ever spot it, in all likelihood.